# Security concerns when changing permissions in Chrome Extentions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on an extension that's basically sending out an XHR request and parsing/displaying incoming XML. Ideally I'd like to let users enter the URL they want to send the request to, but to do this I believe I need to change the URL specified in the manifest.json every time the user enters a new URL. Are there any security concerns I should be aware of if implemented? If not I figure just setting the permission to `*://*/*` might be easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you are letting the user select a URL, you have 2 approaches.

1. Just allow `"<all_urls>"` in the manifest (slightly stronger than `"*://*/*"`). Unless you're doing something specifically bad (like `eval` or exposing your internals using `web_accessible_resources`), the only security risk is yourself.
2. A fancy approach would be to use [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions). You put `"<all_urls>"` in optional permissions then request permissions for new hosts at runtime.

   Pros: No scary dialog on install; give the power users comfort in knowing they provided only granular access.

   Cons: A permission dialog will appear every time you need new permissions.